# Decrypting a A256GCM-encrypted JWT in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, decode

so i'm trying to decrypt a JWT (that i get in context of "German Post-ID") in PHP and i've tried a couple of libraries for that, mainly '[firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)' as its some easy to use library with a decryption-function.

Unfortunately it doesn't support A256GCM-algorithm so i ended up with '[spomky-labs/jose](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose)', but it seems to not support decrypting and i'm starting to believe that PHP is quiet uncommon to decrypt JWT's (unfortunately im bound to use PHP).
Does someone have experience with this kind of JWT and / or have a recommendation for a working library?

Thanks in advance for any answers and, since it's my first post, feel free to leave any suggestions how i could make my posts better.

Answer (score 3):

The [spomky-labs/jose](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) fully supports AES GCM encrypted tokens. It is tested using the test vectors from the [RFC7520](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7520) and based [on a library](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm) that is also tested with vector from the [NIST](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm/blob/master/tests/NistTest.php) and [IEEE802](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm/blob/master/tests/IEEE802Test.php).

However a bug may exist so I suggest you to [open an issue on the library repository](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm/issues) and share more information about that issue (tokens, key, error messages and so on).

It may also come from external problems (not related to the library itself) such as your private key, a corrupted JWT, a wrong format (base 64 instead of base64 url safe) or a claim that is not supported and marked as critical.

Could you provide a link to the token provider ? I tried to find information about the German Post ID you mentionned but the answers are related to the OpenID specification and there is no mention of token encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry, but I got the token from my boss and it contains sensitive personal data. But I am sure that the token is valid and working as one of my colleagues was able to decode the token in the nimbus lib for java - but thats just a backup-plan right now because our backend is written in PHP. This is the API of the Post-ID i am getting my information from [link](https://www.deutschepost.de/content/dam/dpag/images/P_p/Postident/downloads/postid-id-card-api-en.pdf)

Comment: @xpt: Can you contact me in private on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm). Will try to debug it with you.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this is, for now, not longer my task as i'm an apprentice and this seems to be above my knowledge of the matter. I've put a link in the comments of the ticket and i hope the colleague will contact you if he gets stuck. But thank you a lot for your effort so far, i really appreciate that!